# App Inventor App apk file reloads screen every second

Tags: android, apk, app-inventor

I created an app in AI2. Its still building but i wanted to check out its speed and efficiency in the apk file format so i build the app but the home screen reloads every second and i am just able to see something and it loads and again. I checked my code there is no timers there was a while loop which I have deleted. I can't figure out what is the problem.

[image: first screenshot]
[image: second screenshot]
[image: third screenshot]
[image: fourth screenshot]

Comment: well, without a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks unfortunately we will not be able to help...

Comment: @taifun sorry. I've added them now. Please can you help me with it now

Comment: The blocks in the screenshot look fine. Some questions: 1. How do you open the *Home_screen*? 2. Do you have the same problem after disabling all blocks in the `Home_screen.Initialize` event? 3. Do you use a  `clock` component in screen *Home_Screen* or *Screen1*? If yes, how does the `Clock.Timer` event look like?

Comment: Thanks a lot @taifun !!! I thought about every question and in the end the problem was that the Screen1 (Splash screen) had a timer which opened the home screen. I opened the homescreen but forgot to set 'timerEnabled' to false. This made the home screen to open the after every second which also hanged up my android. Please post the answer for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are the following possibilities

1. "something" in the Home_screen.Initialize event might trigger the reload, to find out if this is the problem, just disable all blocks in the `Home_screen.Initialize` event
2. A `clock` component in screen *Home_screen* or *Screen1* might be the issue. Just check how the `Clock.Timer` event looks like and if you disable the `clock` again after calling it

As you mentioned in the comments, #2 was the issue and you forgot to disable the `clock` component in *Screen1*

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of a clock trigger in the previous screen. When you change your screen disable the clock and enable the next screen.

Comment: The question was already answered last year in April and that answer already has been accepted. You should concentrate in answering questions, which did not receive an answer...